# How to stop an overloop output in a class?

Tags: c++, class

So I have an assignment for a class where I have to convert an employee payroll program into a class. I've completed that part and can even generate an output, but the problem starts there. The output keeps looping. I've had this problem before when I had an earlier program and the way I set the while loop was wrong. But this time, the while statement is fine, but the program still loops. I've corrected other errors but still cannot find this one.

Here is the code I've come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class payroll {
    ifstream fin;
    char employeeid[12];
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    char SMH;
    int SSN, hoursworked, overtimehours;
    double hourlyrate, regularpay, overtimepay, grosspay, taxrate, taxamount, netpay, sum, average;


public:
    payroll(){

        fin.open("employee.txt");

    }//CONSTRUCTOR

    ~payroll();

private:
    void calcgrosspay() {

        grosspay = regularpay + overtimepay;

        if (hoursworked > 40) {
            overtimehours = hoursworked - 40;
            overtimepay = overtimehours * hourlyrate * 1.5;
            regularpay = 40 * hourlyrate;
        }//if

        else {
            overtimehours = 0;
            overtimepay = 0;
            regularpay = hoursworked * hourlyrate;
        }//else
    }//for

    void calctax() {

        if (grosspay >= 500) taxrate = .30;
        else if (grosspay>200.00) taxrate = .20;
        else taxrate = .10;
        if (SMH == 'S' || SMH == 's')
            taxrate = taxrate + .05;
        taxamount = grosspay*taxrate;
    }//for end of grosspay and set taxrate FOR

    void calcNetpay() {
        netpay = grosspay - taxamount;
    }//end of calcnetpay function


    void printheadings() {

        cout << setw(49) << "-Payroll Report-" << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "ID  First Name Last Name Stat SSN HW  HR  OT  OP   GP   Tax  Net" << endl;
        cout << "==============================================================================" << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    }//printheadings

    void printdata() {
        setprecision(2);
        cout << setw(14) << employeeid
        << setw(16) << firstname
        << setw(15) << lastname
        << setw(6) << SMH
        << setw(5) << SSN
        << setw(6) << hoursworked
        << setw(6) << hourlyrate
        << setw(8) << grosspay
        << setw(6) << taxrate
        << setw(9) << regularpay
        << setw(6) << overtimehours
        << setw(6) << overtimepay
        << setw(9) << netpay << endl;
    }//print data

    void payroll::findsum(int i) {
        sum += netpay;
    }
    double payroll::findavg(double, int i) {
        average = sum / i;
        cout << endl << "The netpay average is " << average << endl;
        return average;
    }

public:
    void printreport() {
        int i = 0;
        printheadings();
        while (fin >> employeeid >> SMH >> SSN >> hoursworked >> hourlyrate >> firstname >> lastname)
        {
            calcgrosspay();
            calctax();
            calcNetpay();
            printheadings();
            printdata();
            i++;
            findsum(i);
        }//while
        findavg(sum, i);
    }//print data report

};  // end of payroll class

payroll::~payroll() {
    fin.close();
}//DESTRUCTOR

int main() {
    payroll employee;
    employee.printreport();
    system("PAUSE");
}//main
```

Comment: Perchance, what is the output during all those "loops" ? For that matter, what is your *input* file content?

Comment: Do you have correct output for each iteration of the loop?